# Having several sites on an internal server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, debian

I'm trying to configure an apache server to put several websites on it,  my problem is that when I access the root of the server I'm directly redirected to one of the sites. I would like to access it by putting the name of this site (for exemple servername/site1).
Can you explain to me what I am doing wrong?

site-availables

[image: site-availables]

etc/apache2/sites-enabled/polyvalence.com.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName polyvalence.local
    ServerAlias www.polyvalence.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/polyvalence/public/
    <Directory /var/www/html/polyvalence/public>
        AllowOverride None
        # Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex index.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options +FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/index" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/index.php" but be rewritten to "/index.php/index".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the index.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/index.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
            </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.example.com.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.example.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

content of etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
ipaddress   anothersite
ipaddress   polyvalence.com.conf

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

content of var/www/html folder

[image: var www html]

What I have now

[image: what I have]

What I want

[image: What I want]

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation in your question. Could you please post your samples/urls/htaccess rules in text form in your question so that we can test them too, kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: +1: Please don't post text as image (see [ask]). Also, please make it about programming, not configuration (see [help/on-topic] and the [tag:apache] tag description) to make this question more on topic for stackoverflow (or pick a site where configuration questions are on topic)

Comment: Sorry I've edited it

Comment: @RyanLoche, thank you for editing, could you please do mention on hitting which url you are seeing error? Just mention sample URLs and that will do.

Comment: I have no errors, my problem is that I don't know how to access other sites on the server.

Ideally, I would like it to be like this:

servername = display the apache default page.

servername/site1 = displays the homepage of site 1.

servername/site2 = displays the homepage of site 2.
etc.

Here when I go to the server it automatically redirects me to site1 (here it's named polyvalence)